# How to display cyrillic text with the Popup method in VBS

Tags: vbscript, wsh

I try to show cyrillic text before opening a HTA file through .VBS

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Popup "Пожалуйста подождите...", 1
```

But the text is displayed in incorrect encoding

How can I set the correct one?

ps. and how to add a new line like `\n` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save the script in Unicode format (UTF-16 little endian) and the text should be displayed just fine.

As for newlines, VBScript doesn't support escape sequences, but you can concatenate the constant `vbNewLine` to a string:

```
Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
sh.Popup "Пожалуйста" & vbNewLine & "подождите...", 1
```

Comment: My .VBS file is already in UTF-8 but I still get incorrect encoding. And I don't know how can I set UTF-16 in Notepad++

Comment: UTF-8 is not going to work. In Notepad++ select *Encoding > Encode in UCS-2 LE BOM* from the menu, then save the file.